Login by pyrogram session
I have several pyrogram session files and phone numbers of their accounts. How can I receive the code that the telegram bot sends to the account with a pyrogram?
I tested several methods with chatgpt, but I did not get results

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Welcome to [so]. This is not a code-writing or tutoring service. It is not possible to provide a specific answer without you providing sufficient information to understand your problem. Please see: Why is Can someone help me? not an actual question?  for more details.
